# ColorPicker not working inside JFXPanel inside SwingNode

Tags: java, swing, javafx

In my javafx application I have embedded a swing component. I would like to be able to change colors of that swing component, so I embedded a javafx ColorPicker inside it, so that my ColorPicker is similar to those used throughout the javafx application.

This color picker won't work, whenever you click on it, it loses focus and the popup disappears.

Here is a small example application that shows the problem I am having:

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // JavaFX Pane
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        // JavaFX SwingNode
        SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);

        // Swing JFXPanel
        JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        fxPanel.setSize(200, 50);
        swingNode.setContent(fxPanel);

        // JavaFX Color Picker
        ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();

        // JavaFX Inner Scene
        Scene innerScene = new Scene(colorPicker);
        fxPanel.setScene(innerScene);

        // JavaFX Primary Scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 200, 50);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The colorPicker opens, but does not allow you to select colors at all, or open the custom color dialog. What's going on here?

Comment: My guess (and this is certainly a guess) is that a `JFXPanel` is not really a lightweight component (or certainly won't behave as one when you put something in it that relies on a popup); consequently it's not valid content for a `SwingNode`.

Comment: From what I can see the ColorPicker setOnAction() is never called if you select with Mouse. But you can actually make a selection if you use the arrows (keys) or hover with mouse to switch color and press enter to select it. Hmm really interesting ..

Comment: From the [`SwingNode` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html): *"All the input and focus events are forwarded to the JComponent instance transparently to the developer."* So I guess the issue is that there is some conflict between focus in the popup and in the `JFXPanel` (the `JComponent` in this case). I suspect that this "double-embedding" (JavaFX inside Swing inside JavaFX) just isn't viable, and isn't a supported use case.

Comment: @James_D I suppose the answer might be something like "double-embedding just isn't supported" but I thought it was odd that colorPicker doesn't work when very similar code with a ComboBox of Nodes works, which similarly uses a pop-up.